# SpringMVC config applicationContext.xml should import some-servlet.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

- SpringMVC `applicationContext.xml`(ApplicationContext) should import `user-servlet.xml`(WebApplicationContext) ?

I'm config `web.xml` using `ContextLoaderListener` load `applicationContext.xml`

`DispatcherServlet` load `user-servlet.xml` found controller bean can't references service bean

directory structure

[image]

`applicationContext.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.f.dao, com.f.service, com.f.advice"/>

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
</beans>
```

`user-servlet.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
    <bean id="userController" class="com.f.controller.UserController"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/statics/**" location="/statics/"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/users/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

`web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SpringMVC</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:user-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringMVC</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

### update1

above running found `NoPointException` on UserController because not inject service bean, below is part of controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users")
@Controller
public class UserController {
    private Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(UserController.class);

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "userService")
    private UserService userService;
}
```

if add `<import resource="applicationContext.xml"/>` to `user-servlet.xml` server running is correct.

but in `web.xml` `ContextLoaderListener` have loaded `applicationContext.xml` and again load in `user-servlet.xml` may have some redundency

### update2

I'm in `applicationContext.xml` have config `componentScan`, after rename `SpringMVC-servlet.xml` and remove `init-param` in `web.xml` move file in WEB-INF, controller can't found service bean, inject false

[image]

I'm suppose should import `applicationContext.xml` in `SpringMVC-serlve.xml` ?

UserService

```
@Service(value = "userService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    @Qualifier(value = "userDao")
    @Autowired
    private UserMapper mapper;
}
```

**resolve**

because I'm using `<bean id="userController" class="com.f.controller.UserController"/>` in `user-servlet.xml` so `UserService` bean can't be injected.

after change this
`<context:component-scan base-package="com.f.controller"/>` succeed

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: OK, I'm wanted should import `applicationContext.xml` and `servlet.xml` :)

Comment: No, that is not needed. As I can see you already specified your user-servlet.xml location in the SpringMVC servlet definition. So, this should work fine.

Comment: I do found error, java.lang.NullPointerException
 com.f.controller.UserController.index(UserController.java:34), `service` bean not be injected

Comment: if add ` <import resource="applicationContext.xml"/>` in `user-servlet.xml` should be correct

Comment: problem is here: `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet` both load `applicationContext.xml` it may have some repeat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please change your spring bean config file user-servlet.xml name as SpringMVC-servlet.xml and remove init-param entries. And move it in WEB-INF or map resources folder as root folder in deployment assembly(for eclipse ide). It should work fine.

for UserService issue- check annotation on UserService class. It should be annotated with @Service or any other sterotype annotation and class must reside in componentScan declared package. Also User service must have a no arg default constructor or else you need to instantiate the dependent constructor arg of UserService class.

Comment: I did rename `user-servlet.xml` as `SpringMVC-servlet.xml` and remove init param entries, move file in WEB-INF, server run is right

Comment: `applicationContex.xml` have scan service package, bean config is correct.

Comment: `SpringMVC-servlet.xml` need import `applicationContext.xml`? if i do, controller would get `userService` bean

Comment: OK, figure out :)